# CSS Not Loading with passed Property in withStyles of MUI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a functional react component with a style defined as below:

```
const StyledInnerItem = withStyles((theme) => ({
  bgColor: {
    backgroundColor: (props) => {
      console.log('styledInnerItem color: ', props.color);
      return 'red';
    }
  }
}))(InnerItem);
```

Basically I am trying to pass the props.color as the background color, however it's not even returning red which is set temporarily as the bg Color.
When I log the props, it is returning the color from the first render, and it is adding in the html file. but the styles only get added when I click on my component and the colors get applied to the component.

It works fine when the background Color is not a function and I need it to work the same by reading the color from the props.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be because the withStyles HOC only updates the styles when the component re-renders, but the props passed to the component do not trigger a re-render. One way to solve this is to pass the color value to the component as a state and update the state when the props change, which will trigger a re-render and the styles will get updated.

Here's how you can implement this:

```
const StyledInnerItem = withStyles((theme) => ({
  bgColor: {
    backgroundColor: (props) => props.color
  }
}))(InnerItem);

class InnerItemWrapper extends React.Component {
  state = {
    color: 'red'
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.color !== prevProps.color) {
      this.setState({ color: this.props.color });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <StyledInnerItem color={this.state.color} />;
  }
}
```

In this way, when the props.color changes, the component re-renders and the styles get updated accordingly.